# Javascript not working on Blackberry

Tags: php, jquery, blackberry, jquery-validate

Have a script that using jquery validation. Tested on 2 Blackberry's and neither worked properly.

http://andrewpeller.com/contest/indexTest.html

1st one - Blackberry Bold 
Email validation would not work even with valid email such as test@hotmail.com

2nd one 
Form would not submit at all.

Any suggestions as to how to get this to work? Will jquery even work on the blackberry?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Blackberry browser is very limited in JavaScript. I would not expect jQuery to work well in its default browser.

However, I suggest to try using [Opera Mini](http://www.opera.com/mini/) for the Blackberry. It handles JavaScript much better. I managed to run a few web applications using ExtJS 2.x (jQuery adapter) in Opera Mini on various Blackberry models, without problems.

If you are going to deploy this web page to the public, I suggest using plain XHTML/CSS and do server-side form validation.

Comment: Does "Blackberry" encompass OS or company or specific device...? (Granted this question is very date now ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You will probably need to accommodate users with JavaScript turned off when aiming at mobile devices.

Your form seems to be designed so that it can't be submitted without Javascript turned on. You would have to change this to make it work on non-JS browsers. Make sure you have some kind of server side validation for the fields.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what BlackBerry you have but besides Opera Mini you should also look at the new [Bolt Browser](http://boltbrowser.com/home.html) it is really nice.

Now with that being said.  As a mobile developer for many, many years I always encourage developers and clients to develop their mobile sites without the requirement for JS, whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your BlackBerry browser options - some devices have Javascript turned off by default.

Answer (score 0):

Bolt browser is not supported now. Actually [jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) works on bb5 but breaks onfocus, onblur events. On bb6 it works fine.