# Do popular smartphone browsers have JavaScript enabled by default?

Tags: javascript, browser, smartphone

Do the stock browsers that come with the following smartphone platforms have JavaScript enabled by default/out-of-the-box?

- Android
- iOS
- Blackberry
- Windows Phone 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Android: yes
- iOS: yes
- Blackberry: no, or in a very limited
  fashion.
- Windows Phone 7: yes

Here's a question on stackoverflow dealing with blackberry javascript: [Javascript not working on Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870193/javascript-not-working-on-blackberry)

Comment: I think this should qualify "which blackberry" or what "blackberry" means/implies here (e.g. what about a BlackBerry Torch? -- I have no clue about this device, just playing the devil's advocate). It would also be nice if there was a break-down by major version but ... anyway ;-) +1 otherwise.

Comment: "Which blackberry" is a long and complicated issue that deserves a community wiki.  I unfortunately don't really care enough to do that.  I consider blackberry a "protosmartphone"